# Verifying propriety of MCMC

Tags: markov-chain-montecarlo, posterior

I have a posterior I'd like to sample:

$p(\theta\mid Y)\propto L(Y\mid \theta) p(\theta)$

where $p(\theta)$ is proper, so the posterior is proper. I can write $L(Y\mid\theta) = \int f(Y, Z\mid \theta) dZ$. MCMC on the target

$p(\theta, Z\mid Y)\propto f(Y, Z\mid \theta) p(\theta)$

is much easier than working on the margin. This is all very standard, of course. I have two questions: Is the joint posterior guaranteed to be proper? Is it as simple as invoking the proper $p(\theta)$ to conclude

$p(Y) = \int \left(\int f(Y, Z\mid \theta) p(\theta) dZ \right) d\theta = \int L(Y\mid \theta) p(\theta) d\theta <\infty$?

If not, does the marginal subchain for $\theta$ have the right stationary distribution? (We get this sort of guarantee for parameter expanded Gibbs samplers, for example, but that's a very special case).

In my particular case I can also derive a series of proper "working models" with proper "priors" on $Z$:

$f_t(Y, Z\mid \theta) p(\theta) p_t(Z)$

Here $\int f_t(Y, Z\mid \theta) p_t(Z)dZ \neq L(Y\mid \theta)$ for any $t$, but $\int f_t(Y, Z\mid \theta) p_t(Z)dZ \rightarrow L(Y\mid \theta)$ as $t\rightarrow 0$. If I had $\int f_t(Y, Z\mid \theta) p_t(Z)dZ = L(Y\mid \theta)$ this would suffice to show the marginal subchain has the right target (theorems to this effect are in the PX-DA papers as reviewed in http://www.jstor.org/stable/1391021).